# How to convert an answer to a comment?

Tags: discussion

Recently noticed that some deleted answers were marked as "converted to a comment", i.e. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/15660/594. Is this a moderator only functionality? New users frequently answer when they should comment due to limited rep and it'd be great to convert them rather than just marking them for deletion ...

Comment: Great question Ralph!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, We got that power !!!

[image: Use the force: CONVERT !!!]

Comment: hahaha, awesome, I must be dumb though, how do we do that?

Comment: @Ralph, I believe the "we" that Saariko is referring to are the 3 Moderators here on SF.SE who appear and apply their mystical forces. ;)